# Error 500 after encapsulating handler code

Tags: go

I've inherited code that was done by 2 other developers. It appears that a proof of concept website turned into production code so most all of the code is in main. It's a simple program in theory. The setup is a raspberry pi that controls sprinklers written in go that can set a schedule of turning on different zones. I've successfully encapsulated the relay controller into a package, now I want to encapsulate the schedule api. The part is a fairly straight forward CRUD operations.for simplicity I'll just post where I call it from main and the bare basics in the schedule_handler. so first:

**main.go**

```
func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.LUTC)
    log.SetOutput(&lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   "application.log",
        MaxSize:    10, // megabytes
        MaxBackups: 3,
        MaxAge:     365, //days
        LocalTime:  false,
    })
    log.Printf("System Startup\n")

    parseTemplates()
    loadConfig()
    config.Eth0Addr = getIPv4ForInterfaceName("eth0")
    saveConfig()
    log.Printf("local ethernet address: %s\n", config.Eth0Addr)

    // gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/", mainGetHandler) // homepage
    r.GET("/login", loginGetHandler)
    r.POST("/login", loginPostHandler)
    r.GET("/logout", authRequired(), logoutGetHandler)

    scheduleRepository = nsScheduleRepository.Default("schedule.json")
    parameters := nsScheduleApi.ScheduleHandlerParameters{
        Engine:     r,
        Repository: scheduleRepository,
    }
    nsScheduleApi.Init(&parameters)
    r.GET("/schedule", authRequired(), scheduleGetHandler)

    http.Handle("/", r)
    r.Static("/static/", "./static/")
    config.URL = ""
    // hack - wait 10 seconds for network to come up...
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    log.Println("Starting up on port 80")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", r))
}
```

**schedule/api/schedule_handler.go**

```
package api

import (
    "mysprinkler/schedule"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "strconv"
)

type ScheduleHandlerParameters struct {
    Repository schedule.ScheduleRepository
    Engine     *gin.Engine
}

var parameters *ScheduleHandlerParameters

func getSchedules(c *gin.Context) {
    repository := parameters.Repository
    circuitnum, _ := strconv.ParseInt(c.Query("circuitnum"), 10, 64)
    log.Printf("[ScheduleHandler] getting schedules %d", circuitnum)
    var scheds = make([]*schedule.Schedule2, 0)
    if circuitnum > 0 {
        schedule := repository.Get(string(circuitnum))
        if schedule == nil {
            // c.AbortWithStatus(404)
            log.Printf("[ScheduleHandler] Could not find schedule '%d' in db", circuitnum)
        } else {
            scheds = append(scheds, schedule)
        }
    } else {
        scheds = repository.GetAll()
    }
    c.JSON(200, scheds)
}

func getSchedule(c *gin.Context) {
    repository := parameters.Repository
    id := c.Params.ByName("id")
    log.Printf("[ScheduleHandler] getting schedule %s", id)
    sched := repository.Get(id)
    c.JSON(200, sched)
}

func createSchedule(c *gin.Context) {
    repository := parameters.Repository
    var sched schedule.Schedule2
    err := c.BindJSON(&sched)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("[ScheduleHandler] Error creating schedule %s", err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("[ScheduleHandler] insert schedule for circuit %d", sched.CircuitNum)
    }
    err = repository.InsertOrUpdate(&sched)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithError(500, err)
        return
    }
    logSchedule(&sched, "created")
    c.JSON(200, sched)
}

func updateSchedule(c *gin.Context) {
    repository := parameters.Repository
    id := c.Params.ByName("id")
    log.Printf("[ScheduleHandler] updating schedule %s", id)
    sched := repository.Get(id)
    c.BindJSON(&sched)
    err := repository.InsertOrUpdate(sched)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithError(500, err)
        return
    }
    logSchedule(sched, "updated")
    c.JSON(200, sched)
}

func deleteSchedule(c *gin.Context) {
    repository := parameters.Repository
    id := c.Params.ByName("id")
    log.Printf("[ScheduleHandler] deleting schedule %s", id)
    err := repository.Delete(id)
    if err != nil {
        c.Error(err)
        return
    }
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"id #" + id: "deleted"})
}

func logSchedule(sched *schedule.Schedule2, action string) {
    log.Printf("schedule: %s\n", action)
    log.Printf("***  id: %d\n", sched.ID)
    log.Printf("***  load: %d\n", sched.CircuitNum+1)
    log.Printf("***  on time: %s\n", sched.OnTime)
    log.Printf("***  off time: %s\n", sched.OffTime)
    log.Printf("***  enabled: %v", sched.Enabled)
    log.Printf("***  sun: %v", sched.Sun)
    log.Printf("***  mon: %v", sched.Mon)
    log.Printf("***  tue: %v", sched.Tue)
    log.Printf("***  wed: %v", sched.Wed)
    log.Printf("***  thu: %v", sched.Thu)
    log.Printf("***  fri: %v", sched.Fri)
    log.Printf("***  sat: %v", sched.Sat)
}

// Init creates a handler for the schedule api
func Init(parameters *ScheduleHandlerParameters) {
    parameters = parameters
    r := parameters.Engine
    r.GET("/schedule2", getSchedules)
    r.GET("/schedule2/:id", getSchedule)
    r.POST("/schedule2", createSchedule)
    r.PUT("/schedule2/:id", updateSchedule)
    r.DELETE("/schedule2/:id", deleteSchedule)
}
```

In the log I'm seeing

```
2018/05/20 12:14:36 System Startup
2018/05/20 12:14:36 local ethernet address: 10.0.0.7
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
- using env:    export GIN_MODE=release
- using code:   gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] GET    /                         --> main.mainGetHandler (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] GET    /login                    --> main.loginGetHandler (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] POST   /login                    --> main.loginPostHandler (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] GET    /logout                   --> main.logoutGetHandler (4 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] GET    /schedule2                --> sprinkler/schedule/api.getSchedules (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] GET    /schedule2/:id            --> sprinkler/schedule/api.getSchedule (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] POST   /schedule2                --> sprinkler/schedule/api.createSchedule (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] PUT    /schedule2/:id            --> sprinkler/schedule/api.updateSchedule (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] DELETE /schedule2/:id            --> sprinkler/schedule/api.deleteSchedule (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] GET    /static/*filepath         --> github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*RouterGroup).createStaticHandler.func1 (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:36 [GIN-debug] HEAD   /static/*filepath         --> github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*RouterGroup).createStaticHandler.func1 (3 handlers)
2018/05/20 12:14:46 Starting up on port 80
2018/05/20 12:15:15 admin logged in
```

but when I navigate to /schedule the template is loaded then immediatly i get two internal 500 errors (one for each call to /schedule2?circuitnum=1). Now this code worked before when it was all in main i just moved the methods into the schedule_api file then made an `Init` and put that setup code into it. Having a C# background I'm lost as to why this broke. My first guess is that I'm losing a reference to my schedule handler when it drops out of scope of `Main` but I don't understand why. Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: i think i figured it out. I gotta test to make sure, but it looks like the self assignment in the init was messing up. I renamed the parameter on init to be somethign different and it appears to be working now :D

Comment: I think you'll regret using a global variable here.

Comment: @bohdan_trotsenko I've had my doubts about using it. I'm still very new to go. What would be better practice? making a non-exported struct to hold my values in?

Comment: I advise to have a public struct with parameters, just drop the global variable. Update your functions to be methods on a `*api.ScheduleHandlerParameters`;

Comment: (that's the least; you may update or use a different set of structs/methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly! When you are doing this:

```
func Init(parameters *ScheduleHandlerParameters) {
    parameters = parameters
    // ....
}
```

`parameters` becomes a local variable to this function and next line is just assigning it to itself. And global variable `parameters` still holds `nil` value, was never changed. Which caused error!

Changing function param to something like this should work fine:

```
func Init(shPrms *ScheduleHandlerParameters) {
    parameters = shPrms
    // ....
}
```